# Managing Disk space by deleting the older records when the disk is 60% full

Tags: database, vertica

I am using Vertica for an application which has continuous flow of data. So I want to manage the disk space by creating a cron job which will delete the older records once the disk is 60% full.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? I would start by writing a query to delete the records you want, then schedule that using cron....

Comment: No I didnt try so far. I am planning to create partitions based on date and delete accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Deleted data is not removed immediately
- Deleted records are marked as deleted
- Delete vectors are sets of tuples (position, epoch) that record where and when a row is deleted
- During query, delete vectors for a ROS container are merged with results to remove deleted records
- Delete affects performance
- PURGE is required to delete permanently

https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/removing-data/

- Use partition based on date and **drop partition**
  https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/DROP_PARTITION.htm